# How to restart Nginx in Ubuntu or other linux servers

Tags: linux, ubuntu, nginx, unix

I used this [sh file](https://github.com/dburianov/nginx/blob/master/deploy/deploy_nginx_rtmp_ubuntu.sh) to install Nginx. When I modify the `nginx.conf` and try to reload or restart Nginx it didn't restart. I used below command.

```
sudo systemctl restart nginx
```

gave me

```
sudo: unable to resolve host localhost.localdomain sudo: systemctl: command not found
```

and this one

```
sudo service nginx restart

sudo: unable to resolve host localhost.localdomain nginx: unrecognized service
```

and this one

```
sudo /etc/init.d/nginx restart

sudo: unable to resolve host localhost.localdomain sudo:
/etc/init.d/nginx: command not found
```

Comment: Why don't you work `sudo /etc/init.d/nginx restart` ? This is worked for me just now. @ler

Comment: I couldn't get any of these answers to work, but `cd /apps/laradock && docker-compose restart nginx` seemed to work for me using Laradock.

Comment: The link https://github.com/dburianov/nginx/blob/master/deploy/deploy_nginx_rtmp_ubuntu.sh is not working...

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it a) has nothing to do with programming as such and b) the source of their "install" is no longer available. It's not self-contained, and the answers useless. Frankly it should be deleted.

Comment: @ler Please update the sh file which you have used here...

Answer (score 20, accepted):

File probably is there: **/usr/local/nginx/sbin/nginx**
to be sure You can do:

```
ps aux | grep nginx
```

To kill process:

```
sudo killall nginx
```

And start again:

```
/usr/local/nginx/sbin/nginx
```

Comment: `-bash: /usr/local/nginx/sbin/nginx: No such file or directory`

Comment: `-bash: /usr/local/nginx/sbin/nginx: No such file or directory` Same error for me as well :(

Comment: For those who compile/build nginx from source and/or install it with custom path, I worked my problem with this solution. It made sure nginx is killed all no matter where it belong in the path.

If you got `No such file or directory`, probably you have custom nginx path, which you can get by using `which nginx` command when nginx is running. I hope this helps future case.

Comment: sudo ./ctlscript.sh restart

note: need to run this command in nginx folder

Answer (score 103):

The nginx web server can be restarted using any one of the following command line syntax. Use `systemctl` on systemd based version such as Ubuntu Linux ***16.04LTS*** and above:

```
sudo systemctl restart nginx
```

OR

```
sudo service nginx restart
```

OR (older Ubuntu Linux version):

```
sudo /etc/init.d/nginx restart
```

The same commands can be used to `start` / `stop` / `restart` the nginx server on a ***Red Hat 7*** versions:

```
sudo systemctl start nginx
sudo systemctl stop nginx
sudo systemctl restart nginx
```

OR

```
sudo service nginx start
sudo service nginx stop
sudo service nginx restart
```

OR

```
sudo /etc/init.d/nginx start
sudo /etc/init.d/nginx stop
sudo /etc/init.d/nginx restart
```

***To view status of your nginx server***, use any one of the following command:

```
sudo service nginx status
```

OR

```
sudo /etc/init.d/nginx status
```

OR for ***Red Hat 7, CentOS 7*** and higher

```
sudo systemctl status nginx
```